# Printing out a Hashmap with char array

Tags: java, hashmap, arrays

I'm trying print out a a simple hash map with a string key and char array except I'm not getting the proper output.

Output basically goes:

```
 Key :3  Value :[C@35960f05
 Key :2  Value :[C@35960f05
 Key :1  Value :[C@35960f05
```

Which I guess is the code the char arrays actual location? I didn't google because I'm honestly not sure what this means or what it's called. Could please someone tell me how to fix this or where I might find information so I can find my own solution. Here is my code:

```
public class MapExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Map<String, char[]> mp = new HashMap<String, char[]>();

    char[] words = new char[3];
    words[0] = 'a';
    words[1] = 'b';
    words[2] = 'c';

    mp.put("1", words);
    mp.put("2", words);
    mp.put("3", words);

    Set s = mp.entrySet();
    Iterator it = s.iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry m = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        String key = (String) m.getKey();
        char[] value = (char[]) m.getValue();

        System.out.println("Key :" + key + "  Value :" + value);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I already told you the solution for this in your previous question...

Comment: Use `System.out.println("Key :" + key + "  Value :" + new String(value));`

Comment: Just use `Arrays.toString(value);`

Answer (score 1):

Arrays while be reference types, do not inherit from the base `Object` superclass in Java, therefore they cannot and don't override the `toString()` method to provide a textual representation for themselves.

You can easily write a function that returns an Array as a String or you could use the `java.util.Arrays` class `toString()` method.

```
 import java.util.Arrays;
 System.out.println("Key :" + key + "  Value :" + Arrays.toString(value));
```

It might be better practice to write your own method however, I'll give you a head start with the signature:

```
private String charArrayToString(char[] chars) {
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your value is array of chars (`char[]`). So when you call

```
System.out.println(... + value);
```

you call `toString()` method of an array. It prints something like object descriptor. The only solution is to get the `value` array, iterate over it and create a string out of it. Or call `Arrays.toString(value)`.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in java don't override the toString() from Object, so you just get an @ followed by their hashcode in Hex.

The class Arrays provides several convenience methods for doing things like this; Arrays.toString() being the proper method to print an array, and if you're working with multi-dimensional arrays you can use Arrays.deepToString().

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html